# Can $N!$ be computed in less than $\mathcal{O}(N)$ operations?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, big-picture

The standard algorithm to compute the factorial function $N!$ via repeated multiplications has complexity $\mathcal{O}(N)$, in the model in which each operation costs 1, no matter how many digits the operands have. Intuitively, it would seem that this cost could not be improved.

However, how can we be sure? What if there is some clever equivalent algorithm with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\log(N))$, or $\mathcal{O}(N^{0.998})$? If so, how could we know it is possible, or find an example? If not, why not?

Comment: Usually $f(N)=O(g(N))$ means that $|f(N)|$ is bounded by a constant times $g(N)$. You clearly use the $O(\dots)$ notation in a different sense, and then you should explain in what sense (i.e. define it).

Comment: @GHfromMO I think the question is: can you define N! with strictly less than $N$ multiplications (or additions, subtractions, and divisions also I suppose)?

Comment: @mathworker21 I understand the question. However, the OP uses the $O(\dots)$ notation incorrectly (or at least in a very non-standard way).

Comment: What kind of time complexity are you talking about? What is your model of computation? The length of the output is $\approx N\log N$ bits, hence under the standard computation model and standard definition of time complexity, it requires time at least $N\log N$ just to write the output, hence the function cannot be computed faster than that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda abusing notation here with big O due to factorial being conventionally not written with standard function notation. I hoped the context would've made the intended meaning obvious.

Comment: As for model of computation, we're just considering a naive idealisation of an everyday computer where all basic arithmetic operations take equal constant time. I had more discussion of closed forms in an earlier draft of the question, which clarified this. I'm not really interested in conceptualising things on the level of bits unless someone can give a clever algorithm using bit fiddling. A model of computation where $\mathcal{O}(\times) \neq 1$ is not interesting given the heart of the question is really "is there a smarter/faster way to calculate factorials than just using the definition?"

Comment: Well, a model of computation where multiplication of exponentially large integers takes constant time is totally unrealistic.

Comment: It seems you are interested in the algebraic circuit complexity of $N!$, as in mathworker21’s comment. There is a well known argument that, basically, $N!$ cannot have small algebraic circuits unless factoring is easy. Specifically, if $N!$ has algebraic circuits of size $s$, constructible in time (bit-complexity) $s^{O(1)}$, then integers $X$ below $N^2$ or so can be factored in time $s^{O(1)}$, using binary search to find the least $M\le N$ such that $M!\bmod X$ is not coprime to $X$, which will be a prime factor of $X$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I suggest to post this as an answer.

Comment: Please clarify if the supplied answer addresses the question the way you intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing that you are asking is the required number of integer operations for computing $N!$ starting only from $1$ and $N$, which is usually referred to as *the straight-line complexity* of $N!$ denoted by $\tau(N!)$. (or [BSS model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine), though I am not sure they are indeed equivalent; they are at least highly related.)

And your main question can be rephrased in terms of the standard big-O notation as follows:
$$
\tau(N!) = \Omega(N), \text{ or } \tau(N!) =O(N^{1-\epsilon}) \text{ for some constant }\epsilon?
$$

The answer is the latter. Indeed, there is a known algorithm showing $\tau(N!)=O(\sqrt{N}\log^2 N)$ and if we just want to find a *multiple* of $N!$ then there is a subexponential algorithm $\log N$, though I never checked about the algorithms.

The most relevant references I know are as follows:

1. "On the Ultimate Complexity of Factorials" by Qi Cheng, which shows the subexponential algorithm for computing a multiple of factorial,
2. "ON THE INTRACTABILITY OF HILBERT’S NULLSTELLENSATZ AND AN ALGEBRAIC VERSION OF “NP != P?”" by Michael Shub and Steve Smale, which emphasizes this problem.

In fact, according to the second reference, the complexity of factorial is indeed an important problem known to be connected to the *algebraic* version of the P=NP problem. Namely, if any multiplication of $N!$ cannot be computed in time $O({\rm poly}\log(N))$, then the algebraic version of $P\neq NP$ is true.